# Get list of comments from GitHub pull request

Tags: curl, github, github-api

According to http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#list-comments-on-a-pull-request

I should be able to get a list of comments by issuing the following curl statement, however, it is returning empty, as if there were no comments, any ideas why? or how I can get this to work?

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/37signals/sub/pulls/37/comments" -v
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Notice the text near the top of the [Pull requests API docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/) (under the TOC):

> The Pull Request API allows you to list, view, edit, create, and even merge pull requests. Comments on pull requests can be managed via the Issue Comments API.

So, the API endpoint [you are currently using](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/) is intended for Pull request review comments, not the normal Pull request comments:

> Pull Request Review Comments are comments on a portion of the unified diff. These are separate from Commit Comments (which are applied directly to a commit, outside of the Pull Request view), and Issue Comments (which do not reference a portion of the unified diff).

Since the pull request you are referencing does not have any review comments, you are getting the correct result (an empty list). However, as I mentioned above, the API endpoint you should be hitting is the one for issue comments (just use the same pull request ID since it is equal to the issue ID):

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/37signals/sub/issues/37/comments" -v
```

Comment: For me this is not working, still, It claims, that the body parameter is empty, but when I ad body parameter, it will create a comment. =(, I tried:{"page": 1,"per_page": 30,"since":"1988-01-01T00:00:00Z"}

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that

```
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues/{issue_number}/comments
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{issue_number}/comments
```

do not return the same comments! For example, for pull requests 22878 at [Facebook's react](https://github.com/facebook/react) we get the issue comment ids `[988239459, 988246552, 988274918]` (all starting with a 9) and the pull request comments `[764333623, 764334882]` (starting with a 7).

If you want to have all comments from GitHub, you need to query both API endpoints.

Answer (score -2):

You can click on the date in the header of the comment to get a URL to the comment.
It will give you specific comment URL in address bar. You can copy and share the link with your colleagues to address those.

Enjoy..!!

Comment: This is a useful tip, but it doesn't apply to the question that was asked as it has nothing to do with retrieving a list of comments via curl.