# Are there any ways to get/export list of comments for particular project/branch in Github?

Tags: github, plugins, github-api

Are there any ways to get/export list of comments for particular project/branch in Github?

- Is there available any plugin/api?
- Is Github giving any solvents for
  this?

I found the below question which is related to this but seems the answer is only for getting the comments for a particular commit on Github.

[Get list of comments from GitHub pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198351/get-list-of-comments-from-github-pull-request)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Relevant GitHub api documentation.](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/comments/)

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/comments
```

So if the repository you are interested in obtaining information for is angular, your request would be:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/comments
```

To obtain, all of the comments for that repository, you must know their Api limits to 100 results per request(and has some other limits, such as 60 unauthenticated requests per hour). So depending on how programmatically you are doing this, you would want to make your requests as follows:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/comments?page=1&per_page=100
https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/comments?page=2&per_page=100
etc...
```

**UPDATE:**
Following the additional information provided in the comments, for this to work with a private repository, you would need to do two things.

1. Update the url you are using to https://api.github.com/user/repos/{owner}/{repo}/comments
   [Documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/)
2. Provide the appropriate authentication to the requests. One way to do this is through the headers. Add both of the following headers:

   - User-Agent: 'YOUR_USERNAME'
   - Authorization: 'token YOUR_TOKEN'

Comment: Thank you @peinearydevelopment , But I am looking for a solution to get the comments for a private repository. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be any different. I don't have any private repos, so I'm not sure, but I would think you would just have to include authorization headers as well. `User-Agent: 'YOUR_USERNAME'`, `Authorization: 'token YOUR_TOKEN'`. I have an example of this in .NET on a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/peinearydevelopment/GithubDataGrabber/blob/master/Program.cs). Look at lines 46, 47. Hope this helps.

Comment: In addition to the above headers, you will also need to add user to the url as [documented here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/). So you would want to use `https://api.github.com/user/repos/angular/angular/comments`.